# From where is Wi-Fi signal transmitted when replacing 4G router antenna with outdoor antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, antenna

1. I use a **4G LTE router.**
2. It provides an **internet connection** to my PC and is connected via **LAN**
3. My **iPhone** is connected to it via Wi-Fi.

I am thinking about using an **outdoor antenna** to boost my internet signal.

From where is the Wi-Fi signal transmitted and received when I replace the router's antenna with the outdoor antenna? Violet or orange (see below picture 1)?

I wonder if my router uses its antenna for **transmitting and receiving** internet signals at the same time.
Should I install an outdoor antenna with **only 1 cable** and the other for Wi-Fi in my room? (see below picture 2)

[image: Orange: outdoor antenna and iPhone. Violet: router and iPhone]

- Router: [DLink dwr-921](https://www.advice.co.th/product/modem-router/3g-4g-router/4g-router-d-link-dwr-921-wireless-n300)
- Outdoor antenna:  [4G/3G External Antenna 12dBi SMA Male](https://shopee.co.th/-New-WiFi-Antenna-4G-LTE-Antena-SMA-12DBi-Omni-Antenne-Male-5M-Dual-Cable-2.4GHz-for-B315-E8372-E3372-ZTE-Routers-SMA-Male-i.127664302.9864334782)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0k4C.png)<<<

Comment: Some routers can be configured to only broadcast on specific antennas and only receive on others, however I don't believe antennas can be configured in the way you're asking, as the antennas connect to the radio(s), the radio(s) connect to the CPU, which provides the physical WAN and LAN interface(s), then the OS firmware splits the interface(s) into vLANs, applying the vLANs to the physical LAN ports and bridged WiFi networks.

Comment: “where wifi signal release when i remove  4g router's antenna and replace with outdoor antenna?” I utterly do not understand what this means. I realize there might be a language issue here, but still I am unclear on what the core question here is.

Comment: @Giacomo I believe they're asking "From where is the Wi-Fi signal transmitted when replacing a 4G router's antenna with an outdoor antenna?".

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know the antenna design for that router without seeing much more detailed technical information that most vendors don't publish. The two external stick antennas may be WLAN-only (Wi-Fi-only), and the WWAN (4G) antenna may be internal.

Unless you can learn the details of the antenna configuration of your router, your question is not answerable.

Comment: i am not sure even if my router supported by outdoor antenna.